# Inheriting from a User Control in WPF - members are not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I am posting the following question after having reading all the previous answers regarding the same argument. None of them worked.

I am creating a Wizard, and it is composed of a certain number of Slides. 
Every Slide is a User Control, and inherits from a Base Class called "SlideBase"

```
public abstract class SlideBase: System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{

    #region DependecyProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterOptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilterOption", typeof(FilterOptionsBase), typeof(SlideBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,OnFilterChanged));

    private static void OnFilterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SlideBase s = (SlideBase)d;
        (s.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = (FilterOptionsBase)e.NewValue;

    }
    public FilterOptionsBase FilterOption
    {
        get
        {
            return (FilterOptionsBase)GetValue(FilterOptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FilterOptionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(SlideBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public virtual bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsValidProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsValidProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Cover.XAML inherits from SlideBase in the following way

```
<base:SlideBase
    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:WPFOPS.Model.OperatorLog.Models"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    x:Class="WPFOPS.Views.OperatorLog.FilterWizard.Cover"    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     Width="615" Height="370">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Animation01" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
```

With the following Cover.xaml.cs

```
namespace WPFOPS.Views.OperatorLog.FilterWizard
{

    public partial class Cover : SlideBase
    {
        public Cover():base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded+=(s,e)=> {
                Animation01.Begin();
            };

            IsValid = true;

        }

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]
 **- Projects Configuration:**

It is a WPF Project in VS2015. Target Framework 4.5.2. Platform target "Any CPU".

Any hint is highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: How does the code behind look like, i.e. the class declaration of `Cover`?

Comment: Clemes, thanks for your comment. Please find the update in the question above

Comment: Try to rebuild the whole project and check for other compiler errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS message was misleading.

Problem was related to the StoryBoard element. It must have a key

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="Animation01" x:Name="Animation01" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
```

And from codebehind i need to access it this way:

```
 public Cover():base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Loaded += (s, e) =>
            //{
            //    Animation01.Begin(); // THIS IS WRONG
            //};

            IsValid = true;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }


        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("Animation01") as Storyboard;                   
            sb.Begin();
        }
```

I got to this by luck, because all the error messages from VS were absolutely misleading.

I unloaded the Views folder and the ViewModels folder. I compiled the project with only the ".cs" files inside, so that all namespaces were correctly named and found on design time (in this case, the SlideBase  namespace).

I Loaded again the Views and ViewModels folder, and finally get the Error related to the Storyboard.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Because it should be

```
<base:SlideBase.Resources
```

Comment: That's not necessary. `<UserControl.Resources>` should work as well.